# React button does not bring up linked page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router, href

When button is clicked a blank page opens in a new tab. I would like to be able to click and get new tab to open with to different sites that are shown.

I discovered that having the link like below works:

```
btnClick() {
        window.open("https://www.google.com");
    } 
....................
<ButtonComponent cssClass='e-link' onClick={this.btnClick.bind(this)}>Go to google</ButtonComponent>
```

---

```
import { enableRipple } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { ButtonComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-buttons';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
enableRipple(true);
class App extends React.Component {
    // Click Event.
    btnClick() {
        window.open();
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>
                <ButtonComponent cssClass='e-link' onClick={this.btnClick.bind("https://www.google.com")}>Go to google</ButtonComponent>
            </div>);
(<div>
                <ButtonComponent cssClass='e-link' onClick={this.btnClick.bind("https://www.yahoo.com")}>Go to yahoo</ButtonComponent>
            </div>);
    }
}
ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('button'));
```

---

no errors, just does not link to expected websites.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using `bind` incorrectly.  You do not pass the function parameters in bind, to pass a function with parameters in `onClick()` you use an arrow function. try the following code:

```
import { enableRipple } from "@syncfusion/ej2-base";
import { ButtonComponent } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-buttons";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDom from "react-dom";
enableRipple(true);
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.btnClick = this.btnClick.bind(this)
  } 

  btnClick(url) {
    window.open(url);
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>
      <ButtonComponent cssClass='e-link' onClick={() => this.btnClick("https://www.google.com")}>Go to google</ButtonComponent>
    </div>);
  }
}
ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById("button"));
```

Comment: No real need to use `bind()` when method is called in anonymous arrow function